# Is there an easy way to use pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I made a python program with pyautogui. I want to release this to my friends. But they seldom want to download python and pyautogui. I wanna know how to run this without downloading these programs. Or can you explain me an easier way to use pyautogui for my friends (without using pip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a standalone application so that they can run it on their device.
for Windows you can use [Py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/) 
 
for MacOs you can use [Py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)